# How to install ng on elastic beanstalk

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, angular-cli

I am new to elastic beanstalk, I am trying to deploy my angular-cli app on node.js elastic beanstalk. I am getting following error.

```
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
npm ERR! Failed at the mypleaks-angular@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> mypleaks-angular@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> ng serve

sh: ng: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! mypleaks-angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mypleaks-angular@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> mypleaks-angular@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> ng serve
```

To resolve this I have used .ebextensions/nodecommand.config as below

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "npm install"
```

But issue still not got resolved. my Directory structure is as below:-

```
    mypleaks-angular/
         .ebextensions/nodecommand.config
         package.json
```

and package.json is as below:-

```
{
  "name": "mypleaks-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "auth0-js": "^8.11.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-cli": "^0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: why the question marked negative..?

Comment: Hi...did you find the solution???

Comment: No I tried hard, but couldn't find the solution. :( Do you have the solution or facing same issue..?

Comment: yeah, same here. so I moved to EC2. we can deploy angular easily in EC2.

Comment: For EC2, forcibly we have to use load balancer to map it against name servers and that load balancer cost us. That's why I didn't want to use EC2. If you find any solution or advice, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove this ebextensions:

   ```
   option_settings:
     aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
       NodeCommand: "npm install"
   ```
2. Add:

   ```
   "@angular/cli": "latest",
   ```

   under `dependencies` in `package.json`

   Then zip the folder content, and upload the zip file to Elastic Beanstalk